# Any elegant reason behind the following identity?

Tags: combinatorics

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n-k+1} {{n - i}\choose{k - 1}} i = {{n + 1}\choose{k + 1}} 
$$

Note that the identity is obviously true for $k=1$ and $k=2$.

> For $k=1$
>   left hand side = $\sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} = {{n + 1}\choose{2}}$ = right side
>
> For $k=2$
>   left hand side = $\sum_{i=1}^n (n-i)i = \frac{n^2(n+1)}{2} -\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} = \frac{(n-1)n(n + 1)}{6} = {{n+1}\choose{3}}$ = right side

I proved the above identity using some boring algebra. I used the trick that left hand side is equal to coefficients of $x^{k - 1}$ in the series  $\sum_{i=1}^{n-k+1} i(1 + x)^{n-i}$.

Using the geometric progression trick, we can show that

> $$\sum_{i=1}^{n-k+1} i(1 + x)^{n-i} = -\frac{(1+x)^{k-1}(n-k+1)}{x} + \frac{(1+x)^{n+1}}{x^2} - \frac{(1+x)^k}{x^2}.$$ 
>   Clearly the coefficients of $x^{k-1}$ in right hand side is ${{n+1}\choose{k+1}}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider a $(k+1)$-element subset $S \subset \{1, \ldots, n+1\}$, and let $n-i+1$ be the second-largest element. There are $i$ possible choices for the largest element of $S$, and ${n-i \choose k-1}$ choices for the rest of the set. Grouping the $(k+1)$-element subsets according to their second-largest element in this way gives the desired identity.

Comment: And more generally, $$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n-i}{a}\binom{i}{b}=\binom{n+1}{a+b+1}$$ by the same argument, but letting $n-i+1$ be the $b+1$st element of a subset of size $a+b+1$.